# Google Cloud Platform service account not getting permissions from organisation custom role

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iam

I have the following service account

```
my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Which seems to have the following custom role

```
▶ gcloud projects get-iam-policy my-project  \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--format='table(bindings.role)' \
--filter="bindings.members:my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
ROLE
organizations/123456789/roles/my_custom_role
```

This custom role has the following permissions

```
▶ gcloud iam roles describe my_custom_role --organization 123456789
description: My custom role
etag: kdkdkdkd=
includedPermissions:
- container.clusters.get
- container.clusters.list
- container.clusters.update
- container.nodes.delete
- container.nodes.list
- container.operations.get
- resourcemanager.projects.get
- resourcemanager.projects.list
name: organizations/123456789/roles/my_custom_role
stage: GA
title: my_custom_role-
```

However, when assuming this role (I create, download and login using a json private key)

and listing projects, I cannot see all the organisation's projects but rather only the project the SA belongs to, although I should, given that

- the SA has an org level role
- it has the `resourcemanager.projects.get` and `resourcemanager.projects.list` permissions

Why is that?

Comment: The permission `resourcemanager.projects.list` must be granted on each project that you want to list via a project IAM binding. Otherwise, you need permission at the Folder or ORG level. Same for `resourcemanager.projects.get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see other projects, you need a higher level permission on your org.

> and listing projects, I cannot see all the organisation's projects but rather only the project the SA belongs to, although I should, given that

This is expected, because the project can only control who sees this project.

Answer (score 1):

You may need organization permissions too:

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/organizations/list

```
organizations.list
```